# split string without delimiter and stored in an array using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, arrays

The variable datatype is string .it contain string value like greater than 300 chars. i want to split that string by 150 char and stored in the string array using vb.net

My code:

```
msg = t1("fld_msg")
msg1 = msg.Length
For i = 0 To msg.Length - 1
   strarr = msg.Substring(0, 150)
Next
```

Error:

```
value of type string cant be converted into one dimensional array
```

Comment: Can you give more code? Your code is blurry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a counter to increment the cells in the array

```
msg = t1("fld_msg")
msg1 = msg.Length
dim Counter as Integer = 0
For i = 0 To msg.Length - 1 Step 150
   strarr(Counter) = msg.Substring(i, 150)
   Counter += 1
Next
```

Comment: Have you run your code for the string with length which is not a multiple of 150 ?

Comment: it does not have to be multiple of 150 for it to go through the loop. It can be 200 and it will still execute.

Comment: I didn't consider `Step` to restrict your code for multiple of 150, instead for example if `msg` has 315 characters, Do you think it will it will work? Since in 3rd iteration it will request 150 characters while it only have 15 characters left. My expectation will be an a raise of an exception for this case. May be i misunderstood your point.

Answer (score 1):

Substring returns a value of type `string`.

You are trying to put the results into an array.

Try:-

```
strarr(0) = msg.Substring(0,150)
strarr(1) = msg.Substring(150)
```

Answer (score 0):

Required correction in your code is to assign substring value to `an index of array` "strarr(i)" rather than `to an array` "strarr". Also taking a substring like `(0,XX)` is not correct. Every time it will return a substring from index 0, use `(i*NumberOfCharactersToInclude,XX)` instead. But here 'XX' also matters.

For example,

if string has 311 characters and XX is fixed to 150, it will lead to an error in third substring. So i would suggest you to go with this one: (Assuming Framework is 3.5 or above)

```
For i As Integer = 0 To len  ' len represents possible no. of substrings
    strarr(i) = New String(msg.Skip(i * 150).Take(150).ToArray)
Next
```